# GCC -O3 6.1.1, 5.3.1, 4.1.2 fails to compile a correct executable (recursive merge sort in C)

Tags: c, gcc

The following program is not compiled into a correct executable when using GCC (at least 6.1.1, 5.3.1, 4.1.2) and with optimization -O3 (and also -O2). GCC generates a correct executable with -O0 (and -O1).

The output should be (-O0):

```
Sorted array: 1.000 2.000 3.000 4.000 5.000 6.000 7.000 8.000 9.00010.0009999.00012.00013.00014.00015.00016.00017.00018.0001                     9.00020.000
```

instead of (-O3):

```
Sorted array:11.00012.00013.00014.00015.00016.00017.00018.00019.00020.0009999.000 2.000 3.000 4.000 5.000 6.000 7.000 8.000                      9.00010.000
```

Has anybody an idea of the reason? Is it a bug of GCC?
Thanks!

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double arr[20] = {20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

int merge(double arr[],int l,int m,int h)
{
    double arr1[10],arr2[10];
    int n1,n2,i,j,k;

    n1=m-l+1; n2=h-m;
    for(i=0; i<n1; i++) arr1[i]=arr[l+i];
    for(j=0; j<n2; j++) arr2[j]=arr[m+j+1];

    arr1[i]=9999; arr2[j]=9999; i=0; j=0;

    for(k=l; k<=h; k++) {
        if(arr1[i]<=arr2[j])
            arr[k]=arr1[i++];
        else
            arr[k]=arr2[j++];
    }

return 0;
}

int merge_sort(double arr[],int low,int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low<high) {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        merge_sort(arr,low,mid);
        merge_sort(arr,mid+1,high);
        merge(arr,low,mid,high);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i,n=20;

    merge_sort(arr,0,n-1);
    printf("Sorted array:");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%6.3f",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The `-O0` output is also wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is (at least) one bug.

In `merge` you have:

```
double arr1[10],arr2[10];
```

The work arrays needs to be one larger to fit the watch value (`9999`), so you need:

```
double arr1[11],arr2[11];
```

Comment: Thanks for the observation! The code is indeed buggy. However, it seems that -O0 and -O3 force a different aligning of the data so that the -O0 works anyway...

Comment: That's undefined behaviour for you - it may even seem to work if you are unlucky (since then you might not realize that there is a bug, until later when it blows up in production).

Answer (score 1):

I see identical results between -O0 and -O3 on gcc 5.4.0:

```
evaitl@bb ~/se $ gcc -Wall -O0 -o foo foo.c
evaitl@bb ~/se $ ./foo 
Sorted array:11.000  12.000  13.000  14.000  15.000  16.000  17.000  18.000  19.000  20.000  9999.000   2.000   3.000   4.000   5.000   6.000   7.000   8.000   9.000  10.000  
evaitl@bb ~/se $ gcc -Wall -O3 -o foo foo.c
evaitl@bb ~/se $ ./foo 
Sorted array:11.000  12.000  13.000  14.000  15.000  16.000  17.000  18.000  19.000  20.000  9999.000   2.000   3.000   4.000   5.000   6.000   7.000   8.000   9.000  10.000
```

Of course, the algorithm seems like it is doing strange things, but at least the compiler is consistent.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have 5.4.0 at hand, but why 6.1.1 is not as updated as 5.4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Check your own code before you assert it is correct and blame the compiler. ([The first rule of programming: it's always your fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/))

AddressSanitizer shows the problem:

```
=================================================================
==13359==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff0e9e3f40 at pc 0x000000400c59 bp 0x7fff0e9e3e80 sp 0x7fff0e9e3e70
WRITE of size 8 at 0x7fff0e9e3f40 thread T0
    #0 0x400c58 in merge /tmp/sort.c:15
    #1 0x400f9f in merge_sort /tmp/sort.c:34
    #2 0x400fcc in main /tmp/sort.c:43
    #3 0x7f3d7416857f in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2057f)
    #4 0x400928 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x400928)

Address 0x7fff0e9e3f40 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 112 in frame
    #0 0x400a05 in merge /tmp/sort.c:7

  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 112) 'arr1' <== Memory access at offset 112 overflows this variable
    [160, 240) 'arr2'
```

Comment: Before blaming the source code: check well what the compiler versions that I mentioned in the subject. Zero rule (before first rule): correctly replicate the problem before saying anything else ... ;-)

Comment: ...in other words, if the compiler was consistent, it should have generated the same code for the (buggy) program. I understand that the optimization might generate a more precise alignment of the data... 
BTW: can you please report the exact command line to invoke the AddressSanitizer? Thanks :-)

Comment: The AddressSanitizer output shows your code has a bug, so it is not correct. The fact it doesn't show up sometimes is irrelevant, that's the nature of undefined behaviour (such as accessing beyond the end of an array). Your code is wrong, so it's not "a correct executable" as you asserted, even at -O0 (the bug is not observable sometimes, but it's still incorrect). Compile and link with `-fsanitize=address` to enable ASan.

Comment: In other words: _"if the compiler was consistent, it should have generated the same code for the (buggy) program"_ No. That's not how undefined behaviour works. There is no requirement that code with undefined behaviour has consistent behaviour. http://c-faq.com/ansi/experiment.html

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments. Probably I should have put a question mark at the end of the title, but please note that I wrote "Is it a bug of GCC?": it was not my intention to claim that the code was not buggy, but I did not realize the problem in the first instance. Also please note that this code is coming from the web... I did not write it in a first instance (I should have probably have cited the source: http://codegists.com/snippet/c/merge_sortc_sanjay555_c ). I think after all it can an interesting case study :-)